# Populateing pdf field based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I am building an acrobat form using Adobe Pro,  I have one group with three radio button choices representing property numbers and I need to auto populate a text field with the building address based on which radio button was selected.

Thank you in advance and Happy Holidays

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with...

On each button change the export value

In the Text Field Properties>Calculate tab> Custom calculation script> add this script

var v = this.getField("Radio Group1").value; // Change name to actual name of the group
event.value = (v=="Off") ? "" : v;

Hope this will help others out